# Swift 3 - DateComponents to Label.Text sometimes displays "..."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, nsdatecomponents

This is driving me insane.

I am trying to find the difference in two times the current time and a set time which will eventually be grabbed from the server.

This is the time `getTimeDifference()` function for the moment  it has no parameters.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let userCalender = Calendar.current;
let requestedComponent : Set<Calendar.Component> = [.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second]


public func getTimeDifference() -> DateComponents
{
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"

    let _startTime = Date()
    let _endTime = formatter.date(from: "12/05/2016 14:01:00 a")


    let timeDifference = userCalender.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: _startTime, to: _endTime!)
    return timeDifference
}
```

This is what I have in my HomepageViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelHours: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelMinutes: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelSeconds: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true).fire()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func updateCountdown() -> Void {

    let time = Countdown().getTimeDifference()

    labelHours.text = time.hour?.description
    labelMinutes.text = time.minute?.description
    labelSeconds.text = time.second?.description
}
```

When ever I run this code it may work completely fine for a few seconds however some of the intervals it will display `...`

[image: Working]
[image: Not working]

The question mark (?) produces the images above and removing the (?) sets all the labels as `...`

```
labelHours.text = time.hour?.description
labelMinutes.text = time.minute?.description
labelSeconds.text = time.second?.description

labelHours.text = time.hour.description
labelMinutes.text = time.minute.description
labelSeconds.text = time.second.description
```

Comment: Does each UILabel has enough width for two digits? (For example "24" needs more width than "11".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makes the frame fit the size of the text. What you are looking for is:

```
questionsLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Above code will change the font size to fit the width of label. and also add

```
questionsLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

It will render text properly in label.